# How can a user get a working token from Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-files

I am making an application for Microsoft Teams.

Must get the teams in Microsoft Teams that the user is a direct member of.
If I use the same email under which I registered the application in Active Directory, then getting the list on request to **/me/joinedTeams** is not difficult.
However, if I am using someone else's Teams account, I get an **UnknownError** when requesting **/me/joinedTeams**.

I noticed that after consent and authorization in the Microsoft Graph, the user has a token shorter than mine.

However, it works with other endpoints (**/me** and **/drive/root**).
Permissions are exposed in accordance with the documentation.

**Permissions:**

```
Directory.Read.All
Directory.ReadWrite.All
email
Files.Read
Files.Read.All
Files.Read.Selected
Group.Read.All
Group.ReadWrite.All
offline_access
openid
profile
Team.ReadBasic.All
TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForChat.All
TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForTeam.All
TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForUser.All
TeamSettings.Read.All
TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All
User.Read
User.Read.All
User.ReadWrite.All
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyRAP.png)

Comment: Are you using a personal accounts?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a personal account for testing @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: `me/JoinedTeams` doesn't support [Personal Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: But works on `/me` and `/drive/root` because they are supported for personal accounts.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: But when I send a request to /me/drive/root/search(q='') I get a 403 response with an accessDenied error
Although I have set all the permissions that are described in the documentation for this endpoint @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: Is this happening only with personal accounts?

Comment: Yes, this only happens with personal accounts  @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: Can you check if your access token has the [required permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)?

Comment: I checked, all permissions from this documentation are in the appendix @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: Could you please share the screenshots of those permissions you assigned and the code that you used for making this graph call.

Comment: Screenshots of permissions - https://i.imgur.com/qFWA660.png
I make requests in Postman.- https://i.imgur.com/lMFnBi2.png @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: Ok, use that bearer token and put it in https://jwt.ms to see if the you has permission in it or not.

Comment: I noticed that the tokens of a private user and account organizational directory differ.
Private account - https://i.imgur.com/Fipbpog.png
Account organizational directory - https://i.imgur.com/wz9WWrh.png
@ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: Yes, AFAIK the personal account token comes from live.com, where as for organization the Azure AD sends the access token.

Comment: I also noticed that the length of the token from a private user is shorter than from account organizational directory @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: Yes, it is true!! And you can see the idp claim as live in personal accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are getting the error because the `/me/joinedTeams` doesn't support personal accounts. See this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

It works for `/me` and `/drive/root` because it supports personal accounts. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) and [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).